# Intellij 2020.01 ubuntu dialogue window out of screen can't be moved

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

For example when opening the *search everywhere* the title of the dialogue window is placed out of reach in the screen so it can't be moved.

When trying to move the main screen the dialogue is automatically closed.

I tried https://askubuntu.com/a/836137 this without success, restarting IntelliJ or Ubuntu doesn't help either.

Comment: Do you use external display? May be related: [IDEA-202877](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202877).

Comment: Yes, I use an external display and it's indeed related

Answer (score 0):

A workaround has been given by Jetbrains:

You can add `-Dnew.search.everywhere=false` in Help | Edit Custom VM Options and restart IntelliJ IDEA as a workaround.

Origin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202877

Comment: I could not reach _Edit Custom VM Options_ because that menu dialog was also out of the screen: as a workaround to that I went into IntelliJ IDEA settings and assigned a shortcut to it (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Shift`+`Q`). Doing so I was able to add `-Dnew.search.everywhere=false` to the custom VM options and restarted but that did not help: all the dialogs are still out of the screen.